# Why isn't my || or condition not working here?

Tags: ruby

I'm learning on codeacademy and I am trying to make a redacted program work for each situation including periods and commas next to a redacted word. My code that works as intended:

```
puts "Please enter a value"
text = gets.chomp
puts "To redact?"
redact = gets.chomp
words = text.split(" ")
words.each do |foo|
if foo.downcase == redact
    print "REDACTED "
elsif foo.downcase == (redact + ".")
    print "REDACTED" + "." + " "
elsif foo.downcase == (redact + ",")
    print "REDACTED" + "," + " " 
else
    print foo + " "
end

end
```

I get this in the console:

```
Please enter a value
 I am master, right?
To redact?
 master
I am REDACTED, right? ["I", "am", "master,", "right?"]
```

But, the code that does not work:

```
puts "Please enter a value"
text = gets.chomp
puts "To redact?"
redact = gets.chomp
words = text.split(" ")
words.each do |foo|
if foo.downcase == redact
    print "REDACTED "
elsif (foo.downcase == (redact + ".") || (redact + ","))
    print "REDACTED" + "." + " "
else
    print foo + " "
end
end
```

For the time being, ignore the fact that it would print a period even if it was supposed to be a comma. I'm curious about why when I run this program, every word is redacted in the console.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `gsub` to replace the given word?

Answer (score 1):

The statement `foo.downcase == (redact + ".") || (redact + ",")` is always true in ruby. The equivalent of this statement is: `foo.downcase == (redact + ".") || (redact + ",") != nil`

What you want to test instead is:

```
foo.downcase == (redact + ".") || foo.downcase == (redact + ",")
```

Ruby can evaluate anything as a boolean. Only `nil` and `False` will be evaluated to false.

Comment: Thank you for providing me with a solution. Could you please explain why it evaluates to always true?

Comment: Then can you please mark this question as answered ?

Comment: I am still curious why it always evaluates to true.

Comment: @Looking Because you have `expressionA || expressionB`, and `expressionB` here is `(redact + ",")`, which is an expression that's always true. You're not expressing *"if foo equals this or that"*, you're expressing *"if foo equals this; (new sentence) or that"*. You need to explicitly say *"if foo equals this or foo equals that."*

Comment: I see what you are saying here, that it is essentially associating foo.downcase == with the || on the left side. But this begs the question - why does (redact + ",") always equal true?

Comment: As I wrote above, objects can be evaluated as booleans. That is `if "foo"` will be true because "foo" is not `nil` nor `False`. What you did was `if redact + ","` which is also true because it is neither `nil` or `False`. What can be a bit disturbing at first is that even the empty string (""), 0 or an empty array are evaluated to true, which is different from what Python does.

Comment: @Looking Because only `nil` and `False` are false. Anything else is true.

Comment: Thank you, @T.Claverie, that indeed makes sense for me. Because I am no longer evaluating whether or not foo is equal to expressionB I am simply saying expressionB which is the same as just putting a random number in a boolean condition checker.

Comment: @T.Claverie I would like to mark this as answered, how do I do that?

Comment: You have to accept one of the answers to your question. There should be a button somewhere, but I never asked any question here so I don't know where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [erroneous] check for `foo` being either this or that, one might use [regular expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html):

```
foo.downcase =~ /\A#{redact}[.,]\z/
```

The above will be evaluated to `truthy` when `foo.downcase` matches the value of `redact` followed by either a comma or a dot.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

> `elsif (foo.downcase == (redact + ".") || (redact + ","))`

Let's break it down like the Ruby compiler would:

- `elsif XXX` looks for a boolean value `XXX` (that is, in Ruby talk, it looks at the truthiness of `XXX`)

  - `foo.downcase == (redact + ".") || (redact + ",")` is evaluated. `==` binds less tight than `||`, so the term is split on the `==` first

    - `foo.downcase` returns a string
    - `(redact + ".") || (redact + ",")` is just the operator `||` which is defined as "if the left operand is truthy, then evaluate to the left operand; else the right one". So ruby looks at the left operand:

      - `redact + "."` is a non-empty string which by definition is always truthy, so the result of the `||` is the left side (no matter what `redact`contains).

So, traveling back up the tree, `(redact + ".") || (redact + ",")` is evaluated to `redact + "."` which is compared to `foo.downcase` with the result you're experiencing.

### Suggestion

A rubyish way to express what you mean by `elsif (foo.downcase == (redact + ".") || (redact + ","))` would be:

```
elsif [ redact+".", redact+"," ].include? foo.downcase
```

(Or, alternatively, any number of other solutions, like regular expressions, string splitting etc. - but this variant would be closest to what you wrote, and pretty easy to read for someone familiar with Ruby idioms. Since it involves creating multiple strings and an array, this is not suggested in performance critical loops, but fine if performance/memory use is not an issue.)